# Sign in with Gmail & Yahoo on my iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, email, gmail, yahoo

I will be starting on my iOS app soon.. for the new user to sign in.. I would like it to be

Sign in with FB, Gmail, Yahoo.. Is this possible? I am reading about openID but its a bit confusing...

Also when a user signs in with FB, i automatically get the the users name & other demographics.. will it be the same with Yahoo & Gmail? will the API fetch the first & the last name? I dont need any emails info from Gmail & Yahoo, just the first last name & the country of origin of the email id holder so that it can show in the profile page of the app.

Also I would need to store their email addresses in our database for a feature Facebook Friends.. can I store it without any privacy issues?

Thanks for reading & answering my question

:)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using facebook ios sdk?
For facebook, twitter and weibo logins you can surely use the SLRequest from Social framework, to get the user details like the facebook-user-id, twitter-id , screen name etc. Obviously, the account should be accessed as an ACAccount object.

For google, (I've never tried the Yahoo) the ios sdk is easy. Create a client id ( like the appid for facebook; For twitter I didn't use one), and use it for GPLoginDelegate Methods